# Submit form on enter form react component child

Tags: reactjs

I have a unique scenario where I want to check for an enter keypress and tell the parent component to run the submit function. It looks like this.

The `onClick={this.props.onSubmitForm}` works but I can't get it to submit when the enter key is pressed.
Thanks

Search Component

```
class Search extends React.Component {

  _handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      this.props.onSubmitForm
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="searchContainer">
        <label>
          <p>Search</p>
          <input 
            type="text"
            value={this.props.value}
            onChange={this.props.onChangeValue}
            onKeyDown={this._handleKeyDown}
            className="searchBox" />
        </label>
        <div className="searchButton" onClick={this.props.onSubmitForm}>
          &gt;
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Search;
```

Parent

```
handleSearchSubmit = (e) => {
    if (this.state.value != '') {
      this.searchLocation(this.state.value)
    }
}

handleSearchSubmit = (e) => {
    if (this.state.value != '') {
      this.searchLocation(this.state.value)
    }
}

<Search
    value={this.state.value}
    onChangeValue={this.handleChangeValue}
    onSubmitForm={this.handleSearchSubmit}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just telling, but not calling it here:

```
this.props.onSubmitForm
```

You have to do:

```
this.props.onSubmitForm()
```

to call the function. Also, a better way of detecting <kbd>Enter</kbd> is:

```
var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
if (code == 13) {
  this.props.onSubmitForm();
}
```

Also, a much better way and right way without using the above logic is to wrap the form elements inside `<form>` tag and attach the `onSubmit` handler like this (thanks to [Gayatri Dipali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14522742/gayatri-dipali)'s [comment on my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64828278/submit-form-on-enter-form-react-component-child/64828304?noredirect=1#comment114622461_64828304)):

```
  <form className="searchContainer" onSubmit={this.props.onSubmitForm}>
    <label>
      <p>Search</p>
      <input 
        type="text"
        value={this.props.value}
        onChange={this.props.onChangeValue}
        onKeyDown={this._handleKeyDown}
        className="searchBox" />
    </label>
    <button type="submit" className="searchButton">
      &gt;
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ah, so close yet so far. Thanks

Comment: @ThomasByy I have also given a better way of knowing if Enter key is pressed. Please kindly check the updated answer.

Comment: @ThomasByy Also, you do `onClick={this.props.onSubmitForm}` because you're referring a function but not executing. And you do `this.props.onSubmitForm()` because you're calling a function. That's a small difference.

Comment: @ThomasByy Anything else that I can do in this to improve this answer?

Comment: Instead of all these you can wrap it in a form and define a `onSubmit` function with `e.preventDefault()` it's a better and clean way of doing it.

Comment: @GayatriDipali Oh yes! Why didn't I think of it. I'll add that as a section now and give you the credits.

Comment: @GayatriDipali Done, thanks a lot. Happy Diwali too! 